# case class implementation in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, case-class

I'm trying to implement case class in intellij idea, I'm getting below error. Can you please help me to fix the issue:

**Code:**

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("case class")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

case class Employee (empno: String, ename: String, job: String, mgr: String,
            hiredate: String, sal: String, comm: String, deptno: String)

val empDF = sc
    .textFile("C:\\Spark\\emp.txt")
    .map(x=>x.split(","))
    .map(x => Employee(x(0), x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4), x(5), x(6), x(7)))
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:403)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:393)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2326)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$map$1(RDD.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:370)
    at SparkProject3$.main(SparkProject3.scala:20)
    at SparkProject3.main(SparkProject3.scala)

Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: SparkProject3$
```

Serialization stack:

Note: I am using `spark 2.4.4` and `scala 2.12.8` versions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Case classes have a reference to their enclosing class (if any).

So when Spark tries to serialize `Employee` it also tries to serialize the surrounding `SparkProject3` class or object, but this fails because your driver class isn't serializable.

You need to define your `Employee` case class at the top level of your source file, outside the `SparkProject3` class.

Comment: Thanks. its working now. tried defining case class out of main method and with in class also working. update: commented sparkcontext object declaration and used spark session object to create a dataframe, since toDF() is not a valid member of RDD.